# T-SQL - need to run update if only one record returned by query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to update a record IFF there is only one record matching my search criteria.  Here's what I have, but it's crude:

```
DECLARE @TestCount INT;

SELECT @TestCount = COUNT(*)
FROM TestRecords tr
WHERE
    tr.UnitSerial = @UnitSerial
      AND
    tr.PassFailStatus = 1;

IF (@TestCount = 1)
UPDATE
    TestRecords
SET
    Invalid = 1
WHERE
    TestRecordID = 
           (SELECT TestRecordID
            FROM TestRecords tr
            WHERE
            tr.UnitSerial = @UnitSerial
              AND
            tr.PassFailStatus = 1);
```

Of course this is example code - there are more restrictions and tables joins, etc in the SELECT statement, and it's all wrapped by a transaction, but this is the gist of the stored proc logic.

I'm thinking there has to be a better way but I don't know what that is.  Any suggestions?

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it in one query as:

```
with toupdate as (
     select tr.*,
            count(*) over () as cnt
     from TestRecords tr
     where tr.UnitSerial = @UnitSerial AND tr.PassFailStatus = 1
    )
update toupdate
    set Invalid = 1
    where cnt = 1
```

This assumes you are using SQL 2005 or greater.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this syntax, but I like the fact the SELECT statement is only specified once.  Assuming I can get it to work I'll give you the answer credit...

Comment: After a little work getting myself up to speed with Common Table Expressions and debugging the syntax, I got it to work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code will run without problems!

Use @@ROWCOUNT variable to determine how many records was affected by a SELECTE, UPDATE, INSERT statement: but in your case you have just set your @TestCount variable with the same result!

Answer (score 0):

It's not far off what I would do, which is simply:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE y = z) = 1
BEGIN
    --statements
END
```

Of course, you could replace the condition with anything, e.g. a UDF with more complex dynamic conditions.